# Why doesn't artisan work on composer update and return no error messages?

Tags: php, git, laravel-4, composer-php

I've been running into a hundred problems with laravel. I recently upgraded a laravel 3 website to laravel 4, and I saved my entire project into a repository on Github. As I'm constantly having trouble accidentally editing files from the wrong folder, I just created the local git repository in my working directory so I've got exactly one directory to deal with.

Everything was working fine until I tried to install some laravel packages, which I have been able to install before. Whenever I run composer update, ALL of my artisan scripts return an error. The error message itself (presumably a PHP error) does not display, even after I made sure I was using the development PHP.ini file.

```
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
* master [KEY REMOVED] Remove mPDF Library
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error

Status for device CON:
----------------------
    Lines:          300
    Columns:        80
    Keyboard rate:  31
    Keyboard delay: 1
    Code page:      437

Status for device CON:
----------------------
    Lines:          300
    Columns:        80
    Keyboard rate:  31
    Keyboard delay: 1
    Code page:      437

  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:       

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Here's my composer.json (one suggestion I read was to put "php artisan clear-compiled" in "pre-update-cmd"):

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "laravelbook/ardent"   : "dev-master",
        "loic-sharma/profiler" : "dev-master",
        "prologue/alerts"      : "dev-master",
        "mpdf/mpdf"            : "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Another weird thing I noticed was this:

```
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
* master [KEY REMOVED] Remove mPDF Library
```

This is referencing the latest commit in my git repo. Why is it mentioning this? I thought that this might be part of the problem until I realized it was messing up even on a brand new install.

Yes, I have tried removing the scripts or running --no-scripts. I think this is where my problems start, though, because even when I do run --no-scripts I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup' not found in [ROOT PATH REMOVED]/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 46
```

I read that some files may have been missing as I had upgraded to 4.1. So I filled in all the missing files and I got a blank white page.

Based on what I'm reading, a brand new install of laravel should be able to run artisan, or at least after running `composer install`. I can't even get this to work on a BRAND NEW INSTALL. So I updated my xampp installation to the latest version.

[image: my version of xampp]

I also read that there was a way to check if mcrypt was installed: `php -i | grep "mcrypt support"` It stated that if nothing was returned mcrypt wasn't installed, but it definitely returned something.

```
mcrypt

mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt support => enabledmcrypt_filter support => 
enabled
Version => 2.5.8
Api No => 20021217
Supported ciphers => cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes arcfour 
Supported modes => cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value
```

composer update returns no error, artisan doesn't work, it doesn't work when I use --no-scripts and still doesn't compile after I used --no-scripts... PHP doesn't return any errors or log any errors either. I don't know what else to do. I've tried everything I could think of, and everything I could find online. All I wanted was to install a simple package, not run into this huge mess.

I'm hesitant to continue working on this project until I get this issue resolved, but I have to get back to work on it using my still working version of laravel (thankfully I had backup copies of the /vendor files; they weren't being added to my github repo).

But any help on this would be greatly appreciated because I really do need to use those packages and I know I'll have problems in the future if I try updating again.

EDIT: And of note, one common answer I've seen to a variety of questions is to delete bootstrap/compiled.php. Well, no matter what I've never even seen the file generated, let alone being able to delete it.

I even tried running the artisan commands manually (which returned a blank result) and the file never generated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting an answer to this is nigh-impossible. After extensive testing I still found myself no closer to the answer. I don't even know if this is the correct answer, but I FINALLY got artisan to run properly. Here's what I did.

To start, I installed a FRESH copy of Laravel (4.1) using composer:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

Using this composer file (basically the same as the above without the packages require):

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

And running:

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

Followed by:

```
composer update
```

It no longer threw errors at me when I uploaded it.

Unfortunately, I can't get ANY packages to work at all. I think its a bug in the latest version of Laravel, and its VERY annoying. I highly doubt that literally every package broke in 4.1, though its POSSIBLE that this is the problem: http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=55313#p55313

Another possibility, too, is to run composer install first:

```
composer install --no-scripts
```

The "--no-scripts" is optional, if it doesn't install normally --no-scripts isn't needed. At one point I deleted my vendor folder and ran composer install but I couldn't figure it out regardless.

Whatever the case may be, I can't use libraries I added into the app/libraries folder (which I've noticed does not exist by default) nor can I use any composer packages at this point. I'm really not sure how I can get my PDF scripts to work right now... or at least until Laravel fixes these issues.

Comment: running ```composer update --no-scripts``` solved it for me. One of the packages I had was running an artisan script which was failing if I removed that package